# R ggplot put argument in or out aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes

I am always confused about `aes()`. which argument should be put in it and which should not. Is there some principal or rule of thumb? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you make your question easier to answer by giving a specific example of something you are confused about? The `aes()` maps values of your data to properties of the visualization. It's usually not a choice of what goes in or out of `aes()`, usually there's only one way that works.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, which is helpful, the ggplot2 reference page (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) is very clear about which aesthetic arguments are required and which are optional for each plot layer.

Answer (score 4):

If the argument varies based on a variable in the data set, it goes in `aes()`.  So `aes(color = group)` says that there is a variable in the data set called `group`, and that variable determines which color is assigned to each data point/line etc.  Note that you don't state your desired color with `aes` - you tell it what variable defines the groups of observations to be assigned the same color.  The colors get picked separately  with `scale_color_*` - where * just means that multiple options exist here.

If you are directly specifying the feature (e.g. the specific shape, color, line type, size, etc you want), it does not go in `aes` - so `color = 'red'` would not go in `aes` - the color is specified by you, not a variable).  This can be highlighted by the following code:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(50),
  y = rnorm(50),
  z = LETTERS[1:2][sample(1:2, 50, replace = TRUE)]
)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = z)) + # shape is determined by the variable z, so it goes in aes.
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-1, 1), color = c("blue", "red")) # color is specified directly (1st line blue, 2nd line red), so it does not.
```